# Keep reference alive to Singleton object

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

i have a Singleton object that holding a proxy to WCF methods. This Singleton object called from several points in code include as COM object.
My Question is:

1. Is The `GC` can decide to free the object even if i will use it later (for example in COM) ?
2. How can i Decide When `Dispose()` This object? The use of `~Finalizer()` method is good idea ? or may be the `GC` will decide to finalize it before i finished use it ?
3. Is the call `GC.KeepAlive(this)` can resolve the problem ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    public static Singleton GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncObject)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Singleton(); 
                    }
                } 
            }
            return instance;
    }
    public void CallWcfMethod()
    {
        // ....
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    Singleton instance = Singleton.GetInstance();

    public void CallWcfMethod()
    {
        instance.CallWcfMethod();
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class2
{
    Singleton instance = Singleton.GetInstance();

    public void CallWcfMethod()
    {
        instance.CallWcfMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: COuld so plz show some code. How do you manage the instance?

Comment: you've left out the important part namely how you manage the instance. That's is how's the instance declared and how's it used in GetInstance. Class1 and Class2 are irrelevant to answering that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instance is declared as static, it will not be collected as long as the AppDomain is still alive at which point you seldom need to do any specific clean up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop garbage collection you just need a way to keep a reference to the object, the easiest and the one most suitable for singletons is this.

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get{ return sInstance;}
    }
    public void CallWcfMethod()
    {
        // ....
    }

    private static Singleton sInstance;
}
```

So that way you don't need to store it in every class of yours, just call `Singleton.Instance.CallWcfMethod();`

Comment: ok, but if the GC won't see any use of this reference it will collect it, is it true ?

Comment: That question is answered by RuneFS in his answer :) If you dive a bit into the memory and reference handling of .NET you will find, that the GC collects data that is not hold by a root object anymore. A static instance for example is a root object. When there is no other reference left and you null the sInstance, your singleton can get collected. Garbage collection works just by asking "Is anyone still holding a reference to that?" And a static variable is propably one of the longest living referencing, without interfering of course.